# MVC 6 Anchor Tag Helper not producing the expected href

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Fairly straightforward issue.

```
<a asp-controller="Guide" asp-action="Index" asp-route-title="@Model.Title">Read more</a>
```

produces the link ***/Guide?title=Guide_no_1*** but it is supposed to produce the link ***/Guide/Guide_no_1/***

The documentation i can find all specify that its supposed to output ***/Guide/Guide_no_1/*** so I have the feeling there is something i missed, a setting or some attribute somewhere.

the routes i have are like this, just incase they have an impact on link creation

```
[Route("/Guide/")]
public IActionResult Index() { ... }

[Route("/Guide/{title}/{page?}/")]
public IActionResult Index(string title, int page = 0) { ... }

[Route("/Guide/OnePage/{title}/")]
public IActionResult Index(string title) { ... }
```

Comment: Do you have some specific routing rules being applied to your `Guide/Index` action? You might consider posting any custom routes as they can affect how they are generated.

Comment: @RionWilliams posted the one i have, Im not the steadiest on routes, but i think the ones i have should work.

Comment: you have 3  index actions ?

Comment: ye i know, 3 Index methods on different routes with different inputs. Im experimenting, testing and poking around

Comment: and by the looks of it, if i separate the first one off from the following two, the URL goes back to / separated defaulting on OnePage. but i have a feeling the issue will come back on the title/page one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the ordering of your attribute routes.

- Otherwise they will be evaluated in the default order, which is probably based on reflection. The first one evaluated is the route **/Guide/** which matches your specified controller and action, and since it is a match, no further routes are examined.

You need to order your routes so you **evaluate first the most specific routes**. In the case of attribute routing, you will do that using the **Order** parameter:

```
[Route("Guide/OnePage/{title}/", Order = 1)]
public IActionResult Index(string title) { ... }    

[Route("Guide/{title}/{page?}/", Order = 2)]
public IActionResult Index(string title, int page = 0) { ... }

[Route("Guide/", Order = 3)]
public IActionResult Index() { ... }
```

- Please note the order in which they appear in the file doesn't matter, the evaluation order is based just in the *Order* parameter of the attribute. I just wrote them so the order of evaluation is clear.

Now you will notice that you also have a problem with the 2 routes with parameters **Guide/OnePage/{title}/** and **Guide/{title}/{page?}/**. Since they have the same controller, action and required parameters, there is no way MVC can differentiate them and the one ordered first will always win!

- Either use a different action name for one of those routes
- Or assign a specific **route name** to the one that will always lose, so you can create links using that name:

  ```
  [Route("Guide/{title}/{page?}/", Name = "titleAndPage", Order = 2)]
  public IActionResult Index(string title, int page = 0) { ... }

  <a asp-route="titleAndPage" asp-route-title="fooTitle">Read more</a>
  ```

Comment: That is just wonderfull and the Order attr thats just a great thanks